# How to avoid a continuous fraction line going through the equals sign in MathJaX?

Tags: rules, fractions, mathjax

When I use Math.SE, and I type a equation such as:

[image]

I get this continuous line. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Sorry, but MathJaX isn't really on-topic here. While it uses the (La)TeX syntax it hasn't anything more to do with (La)TeX. Also, bug reports, for e.g. LaTeX packages, are considered anyway "too localized" in time on this site. Please also ensure that your title is specific to the actual issue. See @doncherry's edit.

Comment: There is a work-around in MathJax v2.1 for this issue.  This is out in beta now, and there should be an official release within the next week I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug with google chrome, it renders it that way. I switched to firefox and it's ok now.